# json_enode() returns array of objects for singular values

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

The below code has only array like ["a","b","c"] but returns [Object,Object,Object]. The result of which I need to use nested $each loop in ajax success function. Is there any better way to do it?

```
    if($_GET['semValue'])
    {
      $sem_value = $_GET['semValue'];
      try
      {  

         $stmt = $dbConn->prepare("SELECT Semester FROM CourseInfo");
         $semArray = array();
         if ($stmt->execute()) 
         {
           while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) 
           {
             $semArray[] = $row;
           }
         }
        echo json_encode($semArray);
        exit();

     }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
      echo 'Exception -> ';
      var_dump($e->getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: `$semArray[] = $row['Semester'];`

Comment: fix in this before ur "echo json_encode()" ......... header('Content-Type: application/json');

Comment: @splash58: Worked like a charm! Thanks! But howcome if I have mentioned in the query to select just Semester, I still need to specify it in $row[' ']?

Comment: row is always array even if it contains just the one element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're inserting entire `row` in main array so it will return multidimensional array instead of array of string.

To get the array of string replace the following lines.

```
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) 
{
     $semArray[] = $row["Semester"];
}
```

---

**Explanation:**

`$row` would be like this,

```
$row= Array("semester"=>1);
$row= Array("semester"=>2);
// And so on
```

If you follow your current code then your final array would be like this,

```
$semArray = Array ( [0]=> Array("semester"=>1), [1]=> Array("semester"=>2));
```

So it becomes multidimensional array, that's why we use `$row["Semester"]` to make it single dimensional array of string/integer values.

Comment: Thanks! It worked Just another question though, if I have mentioned in the query to select just Semester, I still need to specify it in $row[' ']?

Comment: Yeah `$row` is an array, to select specific element you must use `$row['']`

Comment: So its like an array of arrays? e.g ["Semester"->["a","b","c"],"Course"->["a1","b1","c1"]]?